# How to delete a row from CHANGETABLE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the Change Tracking feature, and I can see change history by using:

```
select * from CHANGETABLE
```

And now I want to delete a row from [`CHANGETABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934145.aspx). How do I do that?

Comment: [Delete Statement Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

Comment: OP means how to remove entries from the [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875) internal tables, not just some arbitrary table named `CHANGETABLE`

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: @mostafa Can you explain why you want to delete a specific row from the change tracking history?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Now that the question has been edited 5 times the meaning is something completely different. However, I apologize to the OP for understanding the question wrong and therefore coming to wrong conclusions.

Comment: @TorstenWalter You weren't the only one who didn't understand the question. But even if you were right, it is still pretty rude / uncalled for. You may notice that if you tried to post a direct link to that URL, it would be blocked. There is probably a reason for that - you may want to read up on [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77377/ban-lmgtfy-links-across-the-stack-exchange-network) [of the](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109713/is-lmgtfy-frowned-upon) [discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) on meta.

Comment: @TorstenWalter that said, +1 for owning up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set up [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875) you specify the retention period and cleanup options:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON);
```

Data will be removed from the CHANGETABLE after the retention period has expired, if auto cleanup is enabled.

Comment: just i want to delete a row from changetable and i need to other rows

Answer (score 2):

since change tracking table is a system table,we cant delete rows from it as in normal tables.So only way is to reset the change tracking table.